# ErrorException: Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Answer::$attribute has no effect

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I get this exception when Answer model I am trying to change value of 'ans' attribute from my answers table database.

```
public function setAnsAttribute($ans){

}
```

> ErrorException: Indirect modification of overloaded property
>   App\Answer::$attribute has no effect

Comment: Can you show some code setting this attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The setAnsAtribute method has no code? If you have code, please add more code to see what is happening. Thank you.

If you do not have a code, I will indicate it below.

I refer you to the Laravel [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) page so you can see the example and attach an example code with what you are trying to do.

```
función pública setAnsAttribute ($value) {
    /**
     *  You can transform the value or modify other values in the table here, 
     *  according to your needs.
     */
    $this->attributes['ans'] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never encountered this error so I did a little research and created the following to illustrate the issue:

**The class:**

```
class SomeMagicMethodImplementer
{
    private $properties = [];

    public function __get($k)
    {
        return $this->properties[$k] ?? null;
    }

    public function __set($k, $v)
    {
        $this->properties[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

**The usage:**

```
$impl = new SomeMagicMethodImplementer();
$impl->bar = 'bar';
print_r($impl->bar); // prints bar
$impl->foo[] = 'foo';
```

**The cause of the error:**

```
$impl->foo[] = 'foo' // Will throw error: Indirect modification of overloaded property
```

> Indirect modification of overloaded property

Using the example code above, this error essentially states that any property created via the magic setter **can** only be modified through the private instance variable `$properties`.

In the context of Laravel and a model, the property can only be modified through the protected instance variable `$attributes`.

**Laravel Example:**

```
public function setAnsAttribute($value)
{
    // output will be an array
    $this->attributes['ans'][] = $value;
}
```