# How to push an array value into database with Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add multiple values to a `names` column in my database. I've set the casts in the model to make this an array.

**Controller**

```
public function add() {
   $id = 1;
   $db = Article::find($id)->first();
   $start = $db->names;
   $db->names = array_push($db->names,'value');
}
```

**Model**

```
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'names' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

This gives me an error message back
`Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Article::$names has no effect`

How do I push (or remove) a value to the array in my database?

Comment: I think this is more a concept of OO. You need to create a setter and getter function for your column to modify them correctly. Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100550/errorexception-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property-app-answerattrib?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the $db->name is not an array, it is an laravel eloquent magic property.

You can either

```
array_push($start, 'newvalue');
$db->names = $start;
$db->save();
```

Or use indeed a setter, laravel also offers a "Magic" method of defining model setters, as in mutators

See: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

I would also consider, not using array push, if it's just a flat array

```
$originalArray = $db->names;
$originalArray[] = 'Additional Value';
$db->names = $originalArray;
$db->save();
```

Would work the same, and might be easyer to read.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried the first thing and it seems to store the number "2" instead of pushing it to the existing array in the database. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Yes, i actually worked from your sample. But array_push does not return the new array but, the actual number of elements on the array.

The first argument is modifed by reference: see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: What about using array_merge instead?
`$db->names = array_merge($db->names, ['newValue']);`

Comment: @Arcesilas Thank you, that solution worked as well.

Comment: Even more fancy, if you would have php 7.4 `$db->names = [...$db->names, 'newValue']`

https://laravel-news.com/spread-operator-in-array-expressions-coming-to-php-7-4